# Nuxt: how to load data to store on app initialization

Tags: javascript, api, nuxt.js, vuex

I am aiming to have a state in my Vuex store which gets populated on initial app load with data from an external API as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
    airports: [],
    pairing: {
        departure: null,
        arrival: null
    },
    loading: false
})

export const getters = {
    getAirports: (state) => {
      return state.airports
    }
}

export const mutations = {
    SET_AIRPORTS(state, payload) {
        state.airports = payload
    },
    SET_LOADING(state, payload) {
        state.loading = payload
    },
    SET_AIRPORT(state, { airport, type }) {
        state.pairing[type] = airport
    },
    CLEAR_AIRPORT(state, type) {
        state.pairing[type] = null
    }
}

export const actions = {
    loadAirports({ commit }) {
        commit('SET_LOADING', true)
        axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat')
            .then(response => {
                // Get each row of data from the source
                const rows = response.data.split('\n');

                // Convert data from row to object
                const airports = rows.map(row => {
                    // Parse the comma-separated fields from the line by using
                    const fields = row.split(',')
                        .map(x => x.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, ''));

                    return {
                        id: fields[0],
                        name: fields[1],
                        city: fields[2],
                        country: fields[3],
                        iata: fields[4],
                        icao: fields[5],
                        longitude: fields[6],
                        latitude: fields[7],
                    };
                });

                commit('SET_AIRPORTS', airports)
                commit('SET_LOADING', false)
            })
    },
}
```

Usually I would just dispatch the `loadAirports` action in the App.vue when working with Vue.js standalone. However, as I am building my app in Nuxt.js I cannot seem to figure out how to load the data to my state without dispatching this method in every page I create but rather just once on app load.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an action called `nuxtServerInit` in universal mode, Nuxt will call it with the Nuxt context. You can use this function to load data or dispatch other actions:

```js
const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }, ctx) {
    dispatch('loadAirports');
  }
}
```

Note that `nuxtServerInit` is **only** called server side (or during compile-time if statically generating). You can implement a similar `nuxtClientInit` by creating a client plugin that immediately dispatches to the store.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: @Philip, thank you for the input.

I updated my `nuxtServerInit ` with the snippet you shared and set the `ssr` to `true` in nuxt.config.js but had no luck to get it to dispatch the `loadAirports`. Any idea what I might have forgotten to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple to do in NuxtJs.

First of all define your initial state:

```
export const state = () => ({
  airports: [],
})
```

Since Nuxt gives access to `nuxtServerInit` inside of your file you can do this:

//NOTE this only works when mode is set to universal inside of your nuxt config

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    const data =  await this.$axios.$get(`your-api`)
      
    // you can do all of your logic here before commiting
    
    commit('setAirports', data)
  }
}
```

than all you have left to do is create a mutatation to fill the state with your data

```
export const mutations = {
  setAirports(state, payload) {
    state.airports.push(...payload)
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input @Creator_!

Do I need to do anything to my nuxt.config.js to have the `nuxtServerInit` action to work?

Comment: Nope, no config needed. should work right out of the box in your store

Comment: I am getting 'Cannot read property '$get' of undefined' when going with your suggestion. Ideally I'd like to stick to my 'loadAirports' action and dispatch it using `nuxtServerInit` as @Philip suggested below. Would you be able to advise how to achiev that? Using his suggestion does not dispatch the `loadAirports` action for some reason...however if I run a console.log() within `loadAirports` it gets returned while the api call is not executed.

Comment: try making the function that calls the dispatch async like so                 `async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('core/load')
  } `

Comment: already tried this approach and the `loadAirports`l action just doesn't get dispatched and neither returns an error.  What I noticed is is that if I `console.log('dispatch('loadAirports')` I get in the console 'Promise pending' message. Still - no idea how to get this action dispatched with `nuxtServerInit`